# HWIOauthBundle - Get Phone from Profile - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I want to get the phone number from a facebook profile, after login through my webApp via HWIOauthBundle. Until now, I've build the facebook login system, save/update e-mail/facebookId+facebookAccessToken in database.

My question is: How can i get the phone number, and how can I save it in my Database?

**my Config.yml**

```
hwi_oauth:
  connect:
      account_connector: app.my_user_provider
      confirmation: true
      registration_form: fos_user.registration.form.factory
  firewall_names: [main]
  fosub:
      username_iterations: 30
      properties:
          facebook: facebook_id
  resource_owners:
      facebook:
          type:                facebook
          client_id:           %facebookApiID%
          client_secret:       %facebookApiSecretCode%
          options:
              csrf: true
```

Comment: I dont think this is possible

Comment: Waiting for more answers... But thanks @SamJanssens

Comment: no problem,   in the mean time, check this for reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/